# rootless + permanent way to change keyboard layout in GNOME 3.28.2 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xkb

I would like to find a way to apply two minimal changes to my current keyboard layout:

· change the behavior of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

· change the behavior of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd>g

While I was successful in doing it using two lines with xmodmap, there are two issues with the soution I am using:

· the current configuration does not survive reboots or screenlocks

· as far as I understood xmodmap has been deprecated in favor of setxkbmap / xkbcomp

I am looking for a way to accomplish the same results in a way that meets these 3 criteria:

1. it works with GNOME and GDM3 (Ubuntu 18.04)
2. it is possible to apply the changes without root privileges
3. the configuration survives reboots, screenlocks and gnome-shell restarts

While I am aware that similar questions have been asked before (and I indeed stumbled upon many of them before writing my own question and tried many of the proposed answers), nothing of what I have read so far meets all of the above criteria. Examples:

· it doesn't require root privileges and survives reboots but doesn't work with GNOME

· it works with GNOME and doesn't require root privileges but doesn't survive reboots

· it works with GNOME and survives reboots but requires root privileges

As a sidenote, I would also like to ask: what is the best / most elegant way to accomplish my goal with XKB?

· creating a different layout

· creating a variant

· using layout options

Thanks in advance.